# For the in.hasNext() function, how does the scanner know we are not past any input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I trying to use scanner to read an arbitrary number of Strings, I use the while loop, the condition is (in.hasNext()). but when I finish type my input the system still wait for you next input which means in.hasNext() is always true. I want to find out if I finish type my input how could I let in.hasNext() return false.

when I finish typing my input, i need the in.hasNext() return false instead of waiting you next input

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    while (in.hasNext()){
        str.add(in.next());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You'd have to close the input console somehow.  I think it's ctrl-D on Unix and ctrl-Z on Windows.  But if you're inside an IDE then I don't know.  Also this is kind of a bad idea, the usual method is to add a flag to the input, like typing "quit".

Comment: @chptr-one I just upload the code

Comment: @markspace I know your mean by use the flag to terminate the program? Is that the only way to terminate the program?

Comment: The system cannot tell the difference between a slow typist and someone who is done.